# can one use \figure with the grid-system package?

Tags: floats, grid-typesetting

Using the grid-system package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/grid-system

Very little documentation on it. When I tried adding a `\figure` in a cell, I get Latex error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grid-system}
\begin{document}

\begin{Row}%
\begin{Cell}{2} 
      test
\end{Cell}
\begin{Cell}{1}

\begin{figure}
    test
\end{figure}

\end{Cell}
\end{Row}

\end{document}
```

now, when I compile this using texstudio on windows (Miktex 2.9) I get the error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

when I compile on Linux, using texlive 2013, I get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: not sure if it would make sense to put a `float` in one of these `Cell` environments; just use the relevant image code without the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`

Comment: Or use `[H]` postition specifier as you are already loading `float` package.

Comment: You do not get the error you show (that would be if you didn't load the grid package). You get `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` which means you can't use figure there (but it wouldn't make sense to use figure there anyway.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was using texstudio on windows, which gives different error and did not notice the error changes when I switch to Linux to compile the file so I can more easily copy the error. texlive 2013 on Linux gives the error I show. But texstudio on windows gives the error you show. Will correct the question now with the correct error message

Comment: @cmhughes yes, when I removed figure it worked. I wish documentation of the package said that so new users would know. If you like to post this as answer so I can accept it. thanks.

Comment: the package is dated feb this year so I assume the one you are using on windows uses a different syntax and you should update it. Row being undefined is unrelated to figure use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating environments such as `figure` and `table` must be allowed to roam freely in your document- when you try to cage them in a box such as `minipage`, `vbox`, `parbox`, and in your case, `Cell`, you will necessarily get an error.

Details of the inner workings of the `floats` and the algorithm controlling their placement are given in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat), which is one of the definitive and comprehensive guides on the subject.

To move forward with your current document, you can simply grab the contents of your `figure` environment and place them in the `Cell`; if you need captions, then you can use `captionof` from the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package.